# Creating a standalone ASP.NET MVC application for Windows XP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-xp, cassini

Is there a way to create an installable (ideally XCopy installable) version of an ASP.NET MVC application that will run in a standalone fashion on a Windows XP machine?

I don't mind installing SQL Server Express for this purpose, so I guess the question boils down to this: *Can the Cassini web server that comes with Visual Studio 2008 be bundled with the application?*  Or are there other options?

NOTE: The installation is for demo purposes only, so there are no licensing problems.  Also, I am suggesting Cassini because I don't know of a way to install IIS7 on Windows XP.  I can't do major hackage on the registry to get this to work.

Comment: Is a VM (with Win7) a potential solution? That would solve your IIS6/7 issue.

Comment: @tvanfosson: How long does it take to set one up? Do I just need Windows 7 and some kind of hypervisor?

Comment: MS has several preconfigured VHD files that you should be able to use with Virtual PC 2007.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it'll help, but you could definitely check out the [UltiDev Cassini Web Server](http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/CassiniDevGuide.htm), which can be bundled with your app and should support what you need.

Comment: Awesome little piece of software.  Works perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: @Robert Harvey - No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You can package, embed, bend fold and spindle [CassiniDev](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com) with my blessings.

I have been told that it suits this purpose admirably.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit old, but check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188791.aspx.

Also, the [ComponentArt](http://www.componentart.com) demos run on Cassini.

Answer (score 0):

My company makes a product for this purpose called the Neokernel Web Server which includes several features that are missing from cassini like SSL support, logging, multi-threaded request processing, and the ability to start/stop/configure the server from your own process.

A free 30 day evaluation license is available for testing and evaluation purposes.

http://www.neokernel.com

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's not really a fit for what I'm trying to do, since I just need the app to be portable within my organization to demo, and I don't need any of the advanced features. If I did, I would stand up an IIS Server.