# ASP.Net web form "not" web API with Owin or self hosting?

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, owin, katana

I have an ASP.Net  webform application , deployed on IIS , now I want to make it self hosted application , I found that Owin can do it , but I am unable to find a way to do it with ASP.Net webform , I have found code with Owin and webapi .I did not found any tutorial or any help  on internet .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a standalone ASP.NET MVC application for Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991978/creating-a-standalone-asp-net-mvc-application-for-windows-xp)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible, I go into the details here http://keyoti.com/blog/asp-net-v5web-apivnextowin-a-beginners-primer-part-1/ but basically Web Forms uses System.Web assembly, and System.Web is coupled to IIS.

You can however self host MVC with ASP.NET 5, if that is any use.

Comment: I have found an API which can do that , its not impossible , take a look at https://github.com/i4004/AcspNet

Comment: @MohammedAsadullah you originally were asking about Web Forms, not MVC which your link relates to.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft only developed Katana/Owin partially and then realized they had to dump ASP.NET WebForms/MVC/Web API/SignalR completely and embraced the new design, ASP.NET Core.

Thus, you can only use Katana to self host Web API and SignalR officially from Microsoft. But third party vendors, such as Cassini, allow you to bundle the web server with your web app, which is another approach to achieve self hosting,

[Creating a standalone ASP.NET MVC application for Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991978/creating-a-standalone-asp-net-mvc-application-for-windows-xp)